# Spring MVC validation with Annotations

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, validation

I'm having quite some trouble since I migrated my controllers from classical inheritance to use the annotations like @Controller and @RequestMapping. The problem is that I don't know how to plug in validation like in the old case. Are there any good tutorials about this?

Comment: This is nice article on this topic: http://blog.jteam.nl/2009/08/04/bean-validation-integrating-jsr-303-with-spring/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Have a look at [§13.11.x of the Spring MVC documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/mvc.html#mvc-annotation). It covers annotation-based controller configuration, including data binding. It should be very useful to you.

Good luck!

Answer (score 5):

Spring 3 includes improved support for validation, and in particular, JSR-303 validation. You can validate form beans using the @Valid annotation and . See

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#validation-beanvalidation

section 5.7.

Answer (score 3):

At a pinch, there's always this thing: http://annovalidator.sourceforge.net/ - it's all tooled around using annotations for validation, and is designed to work with Spring.

Comment: Sounds interesting, I'll definitely have a look at it :-)